# "Login as" URL not fully working

Tags: force.com-sites

We have an internal feature to allow our staff to login as a specific Sites portal user. For that we are using the following URL:

```
/servlet/servlet.su?oid=xxx&suportaluserid={!userId}&retURL=%2Fapex%2FdcEdit%3FuserId%3D{!userId}&targetURL=%2Fapex%2Fms_dashboard&suportalid=xxx
```

The URL seems to work just fine except for the targetURL, which seems to be ignored. So, I tried to find any documentation about this feature, but was not able to. Are there any docs about how to use this URL? Is this a supported feature? If so, what is wrong with the targetURL param?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, I also see a retUrl parameter: `retURL=%2Fapex%2FdcEdit%3FuserId%3D{!userId}`

Perhaps that value is overriding the target URL parameter?

Comment: Removed retURL param, but still not going to the targetURL when loging in. Thanks for the idea, nevetheless :)

Comment: Maybe using retURL instead of targetURL, then?

Comment: retUrl is used for the url you want to go back once you logout from the user account. So, no... that won't do it either. But thanks again ;)

Answer (score 2):

As far as i know you cant choose where to redirect them on login this way, it always just lands on the sites home screen sadly.

If anyone else knows a way around this I'd love to hear it